# How should I refactor and extract these methods in fat User model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, models

I am currently refactoring a User model with over 800 lines of code (with several hundred more that have been added via mixins). Currently there are quite a few methods in the model like the ones below that are simply used to identify a type of user based off of some specific criteria.

```
def is_a_manager?
  # logic to determine manager
end

def is_a_teacher?
  # logic to determine teacher
end

def is_a_parent?
  # logic to determine parent
end

def is_a_student?
  # logic to determine student
end

def is_a_coach?
  # logic to determine coach
end

def is_a_employee?
  # logic to determine employee
end
```

What is the best way to refactor this code? Should I just put it in a concern and Include it in the class? Or should I extract all of these methods into its own separate class such as a `UserIdentifier.new(user).is_teacher?`? Or is this kind of refactor completely unnecessary?

Comment: all the methods basically checking value with a table attribute?

Comment: @ManojMenon they are not determined the exact same way, most might have logic that might come from a related table but not the user table itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use dry concept to check type:

```
def method_name(user_type)
  //logic example
  type == user_type
end
```

call method like:

```
User.method_name("Teacher")
```

I hope this help you.